# RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ for both android and iphone

Tags: android, iphone, chat, activemq-classic, rabbitmq

I need to implement for exam simple chat ( android and ios app ). I need advice based on your own experience what to use, RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ or something else to implement on both platforms on easy way ? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Its been 2 years.  What did you find?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ also works, you just have to include the core library in your Android project.

Comment: Someone recently said that ActiveMQ is not working with android.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189452/activemq-is-not-working-in-android

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ works with Android.

See for example: http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-android-part-1/

I also recommend using Google to find more examples, and checking on the rabbitmq-discuss mailing list.