# ActiveMQ is not working in Android

Tags: android, activemq-classic

I have developing ActiveMQ consumer in android App, and I have included **activemq-all-5.9.0.jar** in my project and set configure build path, but my app is not at all working for me. Below is my code.

```
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
        MessageConsumer consumer = null;
        Session session = null;
        Connection connection = null;

        connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover:(tcp://xxx.xx.xx)?useExponentialBackOff=true&maxReconnectAttempts=-1");
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("xxx", "xxx");
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
        Topic  topic = session.createTopic("jms.topic.test");
        consumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
```

While running the App its showing following error message.

**Dx 
trouble processing "javax/management/j2ee/ListenerRegistration.class":**

**Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.**

**[2015-01-28 15:21:26 - MyApp] Dx 1 error; aborting**

**[2015-01-28 15:21:26 - MyApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1**

How can i resolve this issue and how to make my App work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't support J2EE, or in fact any of the `javax.*` classes, but a subset of the Oracle Java specifications. See more details here: [javax.* cannot be imported in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803343/javax-cannot-be-imported-in-my-android-app).

You'll need to find an ActiveMQ client for Android, or write one yourself (not advisable though). You could try the now-supported MQTT protocol designed for mobile as [documented in this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-mqtt-activemq).

Alternatively, if an option, use a lightweight messaging broker / client - there are many around, with much easier client implementations (for Android here).

Comment: Correct - Apache ActiveMQ broker is not designed or intended to run on Android. But you can find messaging clients that runs on Android that can send/receives message to an external ActiveMQ broker - for example using MQTT / HTTP protocols etc.